# Generate editing interface (textboxes/labels) based on fields in a class

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I have a large number of classes and need to provide an edit interface for the fields in each of the classes.  Is there a quick way to do this?  This is more for troubleshooting/testing, so I could care less what it actually looks like and am not worried about validation, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like a job for a PropertyGrid control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx

[Introduction with screenshots](http://tickblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/the-propertygrid-as-a-hobbyist-game-progammer/) (may be easier to conceptualize thanthe MSDN link.)

Comment: This is perfect.  I currently have the classes implemented with the value as fields (ie, `public short val1;`).  Is there a way to make this control use fields?  I think I'd be ok switching everything to auto implemented properties (ie, `public short val1 { get; set; }`, but would rather not have to.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to use fields.